# OpenDS: Which attribute tells that an account was locked due to password expiration

Tags: opends

I have requirement to show status (locked or unlocked ) of all accounts in OpenDS 2.2. 
I have come to know that pwdAccountLockedTime is present if account gets locked due to too many unsuccessful attempts. So by checking this attribute, I am able to pick account locked due to this reason.
Now I need to identify accounts which were locked due to password expiration. Is there any attribute which tells this?

I need to retrieve this attribute in my java client application.

Any help in this regards would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. - I have checked other threads and forums but none of the solutions given seem to be working - like checking pwdLockedTime (I could not find this attribute).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status of an account and get details of locked account using the manage-account utility.

When the password has expired, there is no marker that it's locked. The server uses the pwdChangedTime and the currentTime to see if the difference exceeds the expiration time.

Kind regards,

Ludovic.