# OpenDS: Set value of expiration time

Tags: ldap, opends

I would like to change the expiration time of my OpenDS-installation. First I'd like to know how to determine what the actual timeout is set to. Later I'd like to edit the timeout but didn't manage to find the information within the documentation.

All i managed to find was the description of the process that describes when a user is marked as 'locked': [OpenDS: Which attribute tells that an account was locked due to password expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222684/opends-which-attribute-tells-that-an-account-was-locked-due-to-password-expirat)

The background is that I would like to set the password expiration time to a very low amount so I can test against some locked users.

All hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password expiration time is computed based on the last time the password was changed. If no pwdChangedTime is set, the server will use the createTimeStamp attribute if present, otherwise, it's impossible to determine when the password is due to expire.

So the easiest way to test password expiration, is to configure it (use dsconfig to set max age in the default password policy), and change the password of the test user.

BTW, OpenDS is no longer active, so I suggest you look at OpenDJ and its documentation.

Regards,

Ludovic.